# How to create a fixe length BigInteger using a String in argument

Tags: java, hash, sha1, biginteger

I use the following code to generate a bigInteger as hash value of strings.

```
public static BigInteger hash(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    digest.reset();
    byte[] input = digest.digest(str.getBytes());

    return new BigInteger(1,input);
}
```

In another hand, i have many ids (BigInteger values) generated with the following code :

```
int idLength = 160;
Random r = new java.util.Random();
BigInteger id = new BigInteger(idLength, r);
```

So i have an id min and an id max, and i want to have all hash values generated by the first code being within the min and the max generate with the second code.
How can I do to have the result of the hash function with a $maxBitLength =  idLength$ (something like $new BigInteger (String str, int numBits)$)

Comment: Please remember that `str.getBytes()` returns bytes in the *default platform encoding*, which could vary from system to system in unexpected and undesirable ways. It is usually better to specify the charset explicitly with `str.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or, on older versions of Java, `str.getBytes("UTF-8")` (or whatever character set you're using).

Comment: thank you @DavidConrad for `str.getBytes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a min and a max value you're expecting, then you should just be calculating `min.add(hash(str).mod(max.subtract(min)))`.

Comment: thank you! i can get the min and the max value but it will generate poor performance in my apps. (i have many ids)